# Mirroring iPhone 5 to MacBook Pro without Airplay

Tags: iphone, ios, macos

Unfortunately my corporate network doesn't support AirPlay. What alternatives are there to  mirroring an iOS 7 device (iPhone 5) to a MacBook Pro running Mavericks?

Note: I don't want to output to a TV because I need to be able to share the mirrored iPhone output via Webex.

Answer (score 3):

Have your Macbook run its own WiFi network, tether your phone to that network, and then you can AirPlay directly without hitting the corporate network.

Comment: That is a fine suggestion, however I don't have the luxury of having a wired connection connected to the laptop. It doesn't look like I can create a network in parallel with being connected to another network.

Comment: Absent an ethernet connection, this is correct; if you do this, you will get AirPlay mirroring at the expense of your network connection.